# MAF Type is empty when using stitch MAF blocks(https://main.g2.bx.psu.edu/)

Tags: alignment, galaxy

We use Galaxy stitch MAF blocks function on https://main.g2.bx.psu.edu/ .

1) Generate BED file of my novel assembled transcript (coordinates based on human reference genome. The file called "human_refseq_nooverlap_bed" below);

2) Log in on Galaxy website. Get Data -> Upload File -> File Format: "bed", File: click and choose "human_refseq_nooverlap_bed", Genome: "Human Feb. 2009 (GRCh37/hg19) (hg19)"

3) Fetch Alignments -> Stitch MAF blocks -> Choose intervals: "human_refseq_nooverlap_bed", MAF Source: "Locally Cached Alignments"; 
[image]

4) MAF Type is empty. Could you help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your BED file check for auto-detection in the edit attributes box. 
Then run again MAF and it should work!